# OP-AMP Circuit help

Tags: operational-amplifier

The attached circuit is one analog hall sensor ([Toshiba THS121](http://pdf.datasheet.live/4137371a/toshiba.co.jp/THS121.pdf))  connected to the op-amp ([Analog Devices AD8554](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8551_8552_8554.pdf)). But I couldn't figure it out how this circuit works. What is the purpose for C9, R9 and C11 R15?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please hyperlink to the datasheets for those devices so we don't all have to look them up. Your post says the op-amp is an AD8554. Your schematic says OP747. It probably isn't relevant but should be fixed or removed.

Comment: http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/32391/TOSHIBA/THS121.html

Comment: http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/48479/AD/AD8554.html

Comment: If you take out C9, R9 and C11 R15 is it any clearer?

Comment: I am really sorry that ,I don't know how edit my question as I am very new to this community.The opamp is AD8554 .

Comment: @alex: Thanks. If you can, hyperlink *in the question*. That way your question looks good and all the info is in the one place. Use the `[text to display](URL)` markup for best effect.

Comment: No I meant if you ignore those parts do you recognize the circuit?

Comment: yes Mr.Trevor ,If i am not wrong , If I took ourC9, R9 and C11 R15 its differential amplifier with offset voltage. But I just wonder what is the purpose for  C9, R9 and C11 R15 ?

Comment: @alex: That's not obvious in your question. Anyone answering would probably waste a lot of time discussing Hall effect and differential amplifiers.

Comment: Well done you are right. So what affect on the input resistors, and the amplifier as a whole. do those bypass RC paths have when you apply a DC vs an AC signal or pulse.

Comment: what I understood is that when magnetic field is nor present beside hall sensor the out put will be offset voltage.once there is a presence in magnetic field change it the current flow path will be C9, R9 and C11 R15.

Comment: I tried to simulate with simulation software. But I don't know what should I give as input signal for hall effect sensor ?

Comment: That kind of depends on what the sensor is attached to, mechanically.

Comment: But I'd opt for 250uV max sine wave to play with.

Comment: Can you please advise me what should I give as input signal from hall sensor( VO- and VO+) to opamp if I am moving (changing field) a magnet frequently in front of the hall sensor.

Comment: I just did .....

Comment: Thank you very much for you great advise Mr.Trevor .I will try to simulate with 250uV sine wave.

Comment: Can you please advise me the purpose of 2 output for this sensor .What is the difference between  VO- and VO+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN this circuit, the Common Mode Rejection will be very poor, because of matching of the 4.7uf capacitors.

I suggest the first stage remove the common-mode, and provide a bit of gain.
Then a second stage provide the HighFreq boost.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve from this circuit is that ,when there is a no change in magnetic field over time I need the out put 0.7 V (DC offset) .If there is a change in magnetic field (even a small change)I need to get a output of 0.7 V + amplified voltage(Gain=330) of the difference of VO+ - VO-.

Answer (score 2):

This is a differential amplifier. It has the following notable properties:

1. It senses the voltage between VO+ and VO- and gives it a little amplified against the circuit ground. That principle cancels some noise which is induced from other circuits equally to both input wires.
2. It provides a DC offset which can be useful for reliable A/D conversion.
3. In addition this circuit provides very  strong high frequency boost. This can be useful, if the pulses between VO+ and VO- are otherwise too low for good timing detection. Of course there's a drawback: The high frequency noise also gets boosted.

I have not a slightest idea how strong and fast magnetic flux density changes are expectable in your application. You are the only one who knows something of the mechanics and materials.

ADD: The linked diagram in questioner's comment is informative. This is a kind of magnetic finger that feels cracks on the iron surface. The flux jumps out of a crack just like it used to do in the recording head of a magnetic tape recorder. Maybe an audio amp+headphones could be a good output method. A trained crack finder possibly can benefit greatly, if there's 2 sensors and a stereo amp. Actually, if I needed such crack finding equipment, I would do some tests using a playback head in the place of the Hall sensor.

I believe the Hall sensor chip is much thicker than the gap in tape heads. It propably is quite blind in front of microscopic cracks which a tape head can catch. This, of course is only a quess.

Mains AC fields may require some attention.

Comment: Thank you very much for the Explanation. magnetic flux density changes in every 1 ms .magnetic flux density  is very small and I need to capture even very small changes,That's y the amplification is very high.

Comment: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Yvs6s047lOI/VRnv9lnRo-I/AAAAAAAAAN0/C8WGFNsiplc/s1600/MFL%2B%E8%8B%B1%E6%96%87.jpg

Comment: @alex the diagram is fine. I added some speculations about it. Should they be removed?